# Access Headers at any time when implementing org.springframework.validation.Validator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-validator

I have a Spring Boot Application where I need to perform some validation over the request's fields based on a header value.

So like any other Spring Boot App my entry point in my rest controller looks like

`public ResponseEntity<Mono<MyResponse>> myOperation(MyRequest request, String another_parameter)`

My problem here is, in order to perform my validations I was thinking on using `org.springframework.validation.Validator`

Whenever you want to implement above Interface, you have to do something like:

```
public class WebsiteUserValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return MyRequest.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
        MyRequest user = (MyRequest) obj;
        if (checkInputString(MyRequest.getSomeField())) {
            errors.rejectValue("someField", "someField.empty");
        }
    }

    private boolean checkInputString(String input) {
        return (input == null || input.trim().length() == 0);
    }
}
```

I would like to get the headers in the `validate` method implementations.

How to achieve that? (get the headers at any time so to speak).

Answer (score 0):

I think use `javax.validation.ConstraintValidator<A extends Annotation, T>` will better.
for example
the Annotation

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy ={SexConstraintValidator.class} )
public @interface Sex {
    //default error message
    String message() default "default error message";
    //groups
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    //payload
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

SexConstraintValidator

```
public class SexConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Sex,String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(Sex constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        boolean isValid =doSomeValided();
        return isValid;
    }

}
```

validate object

```
public class ValidateObject {

    @Sex(message="error message")
    private String sex;

    // ...
}
```

the validate method

```
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
public ResponseEntity<Mono<MyResponse>> myOperation(@Validated ValidateObject request, String another_parameter)
```

or validate manual like this

```
ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Set<ConstraintViolation<ValidateObject>> validate=validatorFactory.getValidator().validate(validateObject);
```